# Adding substrings to array, and the deleting that substring from the parent string

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, substring

I cannot figure out how to do this. My current code is as follows:

```
[string]$strTest = Read-Host "Please input an IP host address in full dotted decimal.`n(Example: 192.168.004.214)"
[array]$arrTest = 0
$str = $strTest
$fs = "."
$index = $str.indexof($fs)
$count = 1
do{
    $chunk = $str.substring(0,$index)
    $arrTest += $chunk
    $count++
    $str = $str -replace ($chunk + ".", "")
    }
    until($count -eq 4) 

$arrTest
```

I want this to give me an array that's populated with each octet of the IP address, but I'm getting a strange result. Running this in ISE gives me:

```
0
123
123
123
```

And I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an array with the octets, just split the string:

```
$a = $str.Split('.')
```

Comment: Was not aware you could do this.

Answer (score 0):

You just messed up parenthesis

`$str = $str -replace ($chunk + "."), ""`

Comment: Damn it, thank you! I've practically been learning powershell as I go. Need to read more into syntax.